# SQL Server SMO script generation throwing deadlock error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, deadlock, smo

I have a huge database with nearly 16k tables. Some of these tables are transnational tables and always receive some insert/select/update queries.I am using SMO to transfer the definition of all these 16K tables to some test database. But my code is failing while scripting tables and throwing deadlock issue (especially while copying those transaction heavy tables). I was just wondering "why deadlock" as SMO internally use some SYS tables to extract definition and shouldn't be messing up with any other transaction.

Stack trace:

```
<SqlException>
          <Message>Transaction (Process ID 670) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.</Message>
          <Server>p01db107</Server>
          <Source>.Net SqlClient Data Provider</Source>
          <StackTrace>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean&amp; dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean&amp; moreRows)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean&amp; more)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.ReadInternal()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.Read()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitObjectsFromEnumResults(Urn levelFilter, IDataReader reader, Boolean forScripting, List`1 urnList, Int32 startLeafIdx, Boolean skipServer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitQueryUrns(Urn levelFilter, String[] queryFields, OrderBy[] orderByFields, String[] infrastructureFields, ScriptingPreferences sp, Urn initializeCollectionsFilter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DefaultDatabasePrefetch.PrefetchUsingIN(String idFilter, String initializeCollectionsFilter, String type, IEnumerable`1 prefetchingList)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabasePrefetchBase.&lt;PrefetchObjects&gt;d__1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyDiscoverer.SfcChildrenDiscovery(HashSet`1 discoveredUrns)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyDiscoverer.Discover(IEnumerable`1 urns)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.DiscoverOrderScript(IEnumerable`1 urns)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptWorker(List`1 urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithListWorker(DependencyCollection depList, SqlSmoObject[] objects, Boolean discoveryRequired)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter.ScriptWithList(DependencyCollection depList, SqlSmoObject[] objects, Boolean discoveryRequired)</StackTrace>
```

Comment: Why not create a backup (or use an existing one), restore the backup to a different server, set the database's `Restrict access = Single_User`, and then script the schema from that database?

Comment: Tried it once..but backup transfer to other server (to restore) is failing due to its huge size.